Earth Engine CLI (Create an empty image collection) under a cloud project
I am using gcloud CLI to create an earth engine empty image collection.
with the second command below it creates the collection inside the legacy assets. I want this to be created inside the project ee-muddasir-shah
earthengine set_project ee-muddasir-shah
 earthengine create collection users/muddasir_assets_workshop/hamzamstestcoll

I am using cloud project and tried so many combinations e.g.
earthengine --project ee-muddasir-shah create collection testcoll2

It executes but when I refresh my assets nothing is there, and when I re run the command it says asset already exists.
That being said, I want this testcoll2 to be created under ee-muddasir-shah cloud asset.

